# Unity error: only assignment call increment decrement await and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have CS0201 error in code. Line number 31, which says

```
hardbody.velocity + Vector3.up * 100f;
```

My code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MyScript : MonoBehaviour {
    protected Joystick joystick;
    protected Joybutton joybutton;
    protected bool jump;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start() {
        joystick = FindObjectOfType<Joystick>();
        joybutton = FindObjectOfType<Joybutton>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update() {
        var rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        rigidbody.velocity = new Vector3(joystick.Horizontal * 100f,
                                         rigidbody.velocity.y,
                                         joystick.Vertical * 100f);
        if(!jump && joybutton.Pressed)
        {
            jump = true;
            rigidbody.velocity + Vector3.up * 100f;
        }
        if(jump && !joybutton.Pressed)
        {
            jump = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The line numbers will change following my formatting edit. Did you mean `rigidbody.velocity + Vector3.up * 100f;` (not `hardbody`) ? Apart from the different identifier, there is no `=` in the expression.

Comment: This code is not C.  It appears to be C++.  Please update the tags to indicate the correct language.

Comment: Also, please do not make us look up or guess what a CS0201 error is.  Present the whole error message in the question body, as text.

Comment: @JohnBollinger this is `c#` ;)

Answer (score 1):

First of all `hardbody` does not exist anywhere in your code.

---

You have a line

```
 rigidbody.velocity + Vector3.up * 100f;
```

but this only returns a value and therefore can't be a statement on its own. You would have to assign it to something like e.g.

```
rigidbody.velocity = rigidbody.velocity + Vector3.up * 100f;
```

which equals

```
 rigidbody.velocity += Vector3.up * 100f;
```

---

General sidenote:

Do not use `GetComponent<Rigidbody>();` in `Update` .. rather store it once e.g. in `Awake` or `Start`

```
// Best already reference this via the Inspector in Unity
[SerializeField] private Rigidbody rigidbody;

private void Awake()
{
    if(!rigidbody) rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}
```

and reuse it later.